# Comunicação entre forms

Tags: c#, wpf

Tenho um form que possui um componente de edição de texto(`RichTextBox`) e crio um form de busca(Find/famoso CTRL + F). A minha dúvida é como faço para um form "conversar" com o outro.
Por exemplo, digitar algo para pesquisar no form de busca e marcar no form que possui o componente de edição de texto.

Pensei inicialmente em passar como parâmetro o primeiro form para a de busca, mas não me parece certo. É certo passar um window para outro como parâmetro? Caso a resposta seja não, como deve ser feito essa comunicação.

OBS.: lembrando que estou usando c# e WPF.

Comment: Se você passar a janela toda como parâmetro, vai criar um acoplamento entre os dois e isso não é bom do ponto de vista da manutenção. Eu só mexi com WPF uma vez então não lembro, mas se você pode passar parâmetros a mais, siga o estilo do Android e passe uma cópia dos dados como parâmetro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei a resposta em um post no próprio *stackoverflow.com*, segue o link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901007/sending-event-between-2-wpf-windows

Aceito sugestão de outras soluções.

Agradeço pela atenção!